# How to get the data of the newly accessed record by a query on PostgreSQL using it's internal variables and functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following 'items' table in my PostgreSQL database:

| id | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 2 | b | 20 |
| 3 | c | 30 |

For some reason I can't control I need to run the following query:

```
select max(value) from items;
```

which will return `30` as the result.

At this point, I know that I can find the record that contains that value using simple `select` statements, etc. That's not the actual problem.

My real questions are:

1. Does PostgreSQL know (behind the scenes) what's is the ID of that
   record, although the query shows only the max value of the column
   'value'?
2. If yes, can I have access to that information and,
   therefore, get the ID and other data from the found record?

I'm not allowed to create indexes and sequences, or change way the max value is retrieved. That's a given. I need to work from that point onward and find a solution (which I have, actually, from regular query work).

I'm just guessing that the database knows in which record that information (30) is and that I could have access to it.

I've been searching for an answer for a couple of hours but wasn't able to find anything.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

*Note: postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-0ubuntu0.20.10.1)*

Comment: You can use your query in IN and again query your table for fetched max value. `select id, value from t where value in (select max(value) from t)` If it is allowed in your case. Or there are many ways but as you described, you can not change the way you are fetching the value.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, @Popeye. The actual questions are about how PostgreSQL works behind the scenes. Does it know what's the original record where the max value are retrieved from? Can I have access to these "behind the scenes" data?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract the *whole* record that contains max(value) w/o bothering about Postgres internals like this:

```sql
select id, item, "value"
  from items 
 order by "value" desc
 limit 1;
```

I do not think that using undocumented "behind the scenes" ways is a good idea at all. The planner is smart enough to do exactly what you need w/o extra work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solution is the one of those I already have using regular select work. Actually, I'm not asking for any "undocumented" solution which - I agree with you - it's not a good idea. I'm just asking for a little more advanced solution using some resource that's already offered by the database server.